# How to determine which session I'm on for OAuth reauthentication in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've written my own custom authentication to work with our corporate OAuth solution.  This results in an OAuth access and refresh token being sent to me. I can then store these tokens in the user collection of the Meteor database but when I want to perform reauthentication I need to be able to find the right session to be able to locate which OAuth token I should use for refreshing it, if required.  Since the user can login from multiple devices, this complicates matters.

This is the code I use to store the tokens and send result on the server-side:

```
            var userId = null;
            var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username: userName});
            if (!user) {
                userId = Meteor.users.insert({username: userName});
            } else {
                userId = user._id;
            }
            logger.info("User logged in: " + userId);

            var initToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();
            var token = Accounts._hashStampedToken(initToken);
            token.accessToken = result.data.access_token;
            token.refreshToken = result.data.refresh_token;
            token.ttl = result.data.expires_in;

            // Need way to bind oath.loginTokens with Meteor resume token
            Meteor.users.update(userId,
                {$push: {'services.oauth.loginTokens': token}}
            );

            var rslt = {
                userId: userId
            };
            return(rslt);
```

And this is the resulting record in the DB:

```
"services" : {
    "oauth" : {
        "loginTokens" : [ 
            {
                "when" : ISODate("2014-06-17T17:51:24.635Z"),
                "hashedToken" : "ErcosEo9rD+IuT3EyFb3DFS8Bf0enwLzkCIf/nP1JFE=",
                "accessToken" : "bhafr3WBDS67EmZ9hFE20af83BJRPFQQS8NGpMlSH6NHVCOiTeTuTJ",
                "refreshToken" : "enOAFkBcxB88FlATUh2m0E5NLLG0y8AojyIH5gItnJXdU6",
                "ttl" : 3600
            }
        ]
    },
    "resume" : {
        "loginTokens" : [ 
            {
                "when" : ISODate("2014-06-17T17:51:24.637Z"),
                "hashedToken" : "uhRZpGdBHnAVKvgBEm7oSWsdflOGRI2YrR9Q21iqjzp+Xc="
            }
        ]
    }
},
"username" : "lous"
```

As you can see from what's above, I need to key off of one of the token values to find the right oauth information to do a possible refresh. On the client side I then do what's shown below, but the problem is that the token returned in `validateResult` is not the same token that is being stored in the DB, so I have no way to track which session is mine.

```
Template.login.events({
    'submit #login-form': function(e,t) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = t.find('#login-id').value,
            password = t.find('#login-password').value;

        var req = {id: id, password: password};

        Accounts.callLoginMethod({
            methodArguments: [req],
            validateResult: function (result) {
                var token = result.token;
                window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);

                subscribeToRequests();
                $.mobile.changePage('#landingPage', {transition: 'slidefade'});
            },
            userCallback: function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("Error: " + error.message);
                    alert("Login Failure");
                } 
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Why would the token not be the same? Any recommendations on how to address this?  Then once I do have the token stored client side, does Meteor provide an out-of-the-box way to test the token's validity?  Here's the findUser method I'm using to attempt to do that:

```
Meteor.methods({
    findUser: function(token) {
        var user = null;

        var hashedToken = Accounts._hashLoginToken(token);
        if (this.userId) {
            //TODO need user object to include token to do TTL check and reauth if necessary
            user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId});
            var result = refreshUser(user);
            if (result.err) {
                throw { name: 'System Error', message: 'The following error occurred: ' + result.err
                };
            }
        } else {
            throw { name: 'System Error', message: 'No userId available. Please try again.'
            };
        }
        return user;
    }
});
```

Comment: Have You tried to store token in browsers cookie for long time to regenerate the session?

Comment: The problem isn't storing the token; the issue is that token I get back from the server isn't the same stored in the user's collection so I'm not able to effectively reauth.

Comment: Of course You will not get same token due the security rules of site. But You can store the token for future use.

Comment: Oh so are you suggesting that the token I get is a proxy for the real one that's stored in the database?  If that's the case, how can I reauth with the token I have stored on the client side?  Does Meteor provide a way to do that?

Comment: I'm not meteor dev, even in another framework resolution of this problem is the same. Try to read about how to store and retrieve data in cookie, and then try to retrive stored in cookie token and then use in block where you generate init token and etc. I think you everytime generate inittoken so thats why it varies. So try to check cookies for inittoken and if it doesnot exist generate it and put in cookie for future use

Comment: install this https://github.com/subhog/meteor-cookies  npm install meteor-cookies and use it.

Comment: Hi @occasl, can I try to clarify what you'd like to do? It sounds like you want to associate an OAuth access/refresh token with a DDP login token (i.e. the thing that you generate with `Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken`), and then be able to retrieve the access token once the user has logged in by looking up the access token associated with the user's DDP login token. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do, but once I have the access token, I'll check to see if it's expired. If it is, I'll use the OAuth refresh token to get a new access token.  I've written the findUser method above to achieve that but I don't know how to tell Meteor what the previous token was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `findUser` method, you can call `Accounts._getLoginToken(this.connection.id)` to get the current login token for the connection. You can then look up the OAuth access token associated with this value.

As for your original question of why `result.token` on the client is different from what's in the database: I think you're comparing the unhashed token (`result.token`) to the hashed token stored in the database. If that's the case, you can pass `result.token` to the server and pass it through `Accounts._hashLoginToken` before looking it up in the database.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks Emily...that's the function I was looking for. But the problem now is that it returns the token under resume.loginTokens and not the token I created in that first section of code above. I feel like I'm doing something wrong there. I've tried different things but I never can get the hashed resume token to align with my OAuth tokens so I can properly search.  I've tried the Accounts._hashLoginToken() but that errors out on me. I feel like I shouldn't need to do this if I can just get the oauth and resume hashed token to be stored in the DB together. Any ideas how to effectively do that?

Comment: A little bit further in that I'm sending the `result.token` that is different from what's being stored in the DB back to the server. I run `Accounts._hashLoginToken(result.token)` and the result IS the hashedToken that's under `services.resume.loginToken`. BUT as referenced in my previous comment this is not the same token stored in `services.oauth.loginTokens` which means I don't have a pointer back to oauth token from the resume token. I'll look into saving them together, but it looks like Meteor saves the resume token on it's own. I guess I could write a post hook to change it..seems hacky.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. The first chunk of code in your question ("the code I use to store the tokens and send result on the server-side"): where do you have that code? In a login handler? Where does `result` come from?

Comment: In a login handler, you can generate and save your own token (with `Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken()` and `Accounts._insertLoginToken`), and then return it as the `stampedLoginToken` field of the result. If you do that, Meteor won't generate its own login token.

Comment: Yes, that code is in my `Accounts.registerLoginHandler` on the server side (didn't include whole because some details about our OAuth server).  As you see, I'm generating a token and I've tried to use `Accounts._insertLoginToken` and Accounts_insertHashedLoginToken` and while they do put the token in the DB, Meteor puts another entry in the DB under `services.resume.loginTokens` after it finishes with my loginHandler and that's the one returned by `Accounts._getLoginToken(this.connection.id)`.

Comment: What I ended up doing to get around this is just write a Meteor method to update the token in my `services.oauth.loginTokens` to match the hashed token that Meteor is using for the session. You can see that in my answer.

Comment: Meteor won't put another `services.resume.loginTokens` entry in the db if you return a `stampedLoginToken` field in the result from your login handler (e.g. if you return `{ userId: userId, stampedLoginToken: token }`). Anyway, glad you found something that worked for you.

Comment: Yup, that's a lot cleaner to do this way, but the thing I was missing is that I must use the key `services.resume.loginTokens` to store my oauth tokens so another one doesn't appear there created by Meteor. Now I don't have to bookkeep the hashedTokens in two separate places...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up aligning my OAuth tokens with the Meteor session token.

I created the following `Meteor.methods` on the server-side and my client just calls the `updateToken` in the `validateResult` of my `Accounts.callLoginMethod` so my oauth tokens can be found by the method @emily describes in her answer.

It calls `reauthenticateUser` whenever the app starts up or is refreshed and finally, it calls `logoutUser` when the user logs our or the session timeout expires.

```
updateToken: function() {
    // Update oauth hash token with correct hashed token
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({'_id': this.userId});
    var hashedToken = Accounts._getLoginToken(this.connection.id);

    // Get last element for OAuth array (safely presuming the last one is the last oauth from current call stack) and update hashedToken
    var oauthObj = _.last(user.services.oauth.loginTokens);

    Meteor.users.update({'services.oauth.loginTokens': {$elemMatch: {hashedToken: oauthObj.hashedToken}}}, {$set: {'services.oauth.loginTokens.$.hashedToken': hashedToken}});
},
reauthenticateUser: function() {
    var user = null;
    if (this.userId) {
        var hashedToken = Accounts._getLoginToken(this.connection.id);
        user = Meteor.users.findOne({$and: [{'_id': this.userId}, {'services.oauth.loginTokens': {$elemMatch: {hashedToken: hashedToken}}}]});

        // Get specific oauthTokens (keep in mind multiples per client)
        var oauthTokens = _.findWhere(user.services.oauth.loginTokens, {'hashedToken': hashedToken});
        var result = refreshUser(this.userId, user.username, oauthTokens);

        if (result.err) {
            throw { name: 'System Error', message: 'The following error occurred: ' + result.err
            };
        }
    } else {
        throw { name: 'System Error', message: 'No userId available. Please try again.'
        };
    }
    return user;
},
logoutUser: function() {
    var hashedToken = Accounts._getLoginToken(this.connection.id);
    // Remove orphaned Oauth tokens
    Meteor.users.update(
        {$and: [{'_id': this.userId}, {'services.oauth.loginTokens': {$elemMatch: {hashedToken: hashedToken}}}]},
        {$pull: {'services.oauth.loginTokens': {'hashedToken':hashedToken}
        }});
    return true;
}
```

Once I had this in place, it was easy for me to update the oauth tokens once they were refreshed or to remove them once the user logged out.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not meteorJS developer, but I'll try to suggest the resolution of problem.

install meteor-cookies using npm install meteor-cookies.
and then:

```
        var initToken = Cookie.get('initToken');
        if(!initToken) {
            initToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();
            Cookie.set('initToken', initToken, {days: 30});
        }
        var token = Accounts._hashStampedToken(initToken);
        token.accessToken = result.data.access_token;
        token.refreshToken = result.data.refresh_token;
        token.ttl = result.data.expires_in;
```

OR:

```
        var token = Cookie.get('token');
        if(!token) {
            var initToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();
            token = Accounts._hashStampedToken(initToken);
            Cookie.set('token', token, {days: 30});
        }
        token.accessToken = result.data.access_token;
        token.refreshToken = result.data.refresh_token;
        token.ttl = result.data.expires_in;
```

maybe there are errors in my additions but I think You've understood the trick. (:

Comment: I think there's a bit of a disconnect. Meteor has two components, a server side and client side.  On the server-side you authn the user and store the generatedStampedLogingToken in the DB and then return that to the client side.  The client side then stores that token, much like I'm showing above with localstorage. Then when a user refreshes the app, we pull the token from localstorage send it to the server and the server compares it with what's in the database.  If the same, it passes; if not, it re-auths.  You seem to show here setting the cookie, but you can't do that on the server.